# How do I get multiple SrgsRules to work in an SrgsGrammar?

Tags: vb.net, speech-recognition

I'm learning visual basic and I'm tinkering around with voice recognition.  I am trying to get a grammar with multiple rules to work, but with no success.  I created a grammar with 3 rules, [search, colors, and root] the root rule just contains `SrgsRuleRef`s for each of the other 2 rules.

```
    Private Sub setColors()
        reco.UnloadAllGrammars()

        Dim gram As New Recognition.SrgsGrammar.SrgsDocument

        Dim searchRule As New Recognition.SrgsGrammar.SrgsRule("Search")
        Dim searchRef As New Recognition.SrgsGrammar.SrgsRuleRef(searchRule)
        searchRule.Add(New Recognition.SrgsGrammar.SrgsOneOf("search", "serch"))
        searchRule.Add(Recognition.SrgsGrammar.SrgsRuleRef.Dictation)
        searchRule.Scope = Recognition.SrgsGrammar.SrgsRuleScope.Public

        Dim colorRule As New Recognition.SrgsGrammar.SrgsRule("color")
        Dim colorRef As New Recognition.SrgsGrammar.SrgsRuleRef(colorRule)
        Dim colorList As New Recognition.SrgsGrammar.SrgsOneOf("red", "green", "blue")
        colorRule.Add(colorList)
        colorRule.Scope = Recognition.SrgsGrammar.SrgsRuleScope.Public

        Dim rootRule As New Recognition.SrgsGrammar.SrgsRule("root")
        rootRule.Scope = Recognition.SrgsGrammar.SrgsRuleScope.Public
        rootRule.Add(searchRef)
        rootRule.Add(colorRef)

        gram.Rules.Add(rootRule)
        gram.Rules.Add(colorRule)
        gram.Rules.Add(searchRule)

        gram.Root = rootRule

        reco.LoadGrammar(New Recognition.Grammar(gram))
    End Sub
```

If I set the "searchRule" or the "colorRule" as the grammar's root, whichever is set will work -- so I know that the rules are working on their own -- they're just not the responding when in the "rootRule."

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I finally figured out the answer:

When adding a rule to another rule, using rule`.Add` doesn't work, however rule`.Elements.Add` does.

Also, it is not complete (at least in my case) to just add a rule reference.  I had to convert the reference into an item first then add it.

And finally, I added both rules/items to a `SrgsOneOf` then added the OneOf to the rule.

Here is how the code in the question should look to work properly:

```
    ...

    Dim rootRule As New Recognition.SrgsGrammar.SrgsRule("root")
    rootRule.Scope = Recognition.SrgsGrammar.SrgsRuleScope.Public

    Dim colorItem As New Recognition.SrgsGrammar.SrgsItem(colorRef) ' <--- '
    Dim searchItem As New Recognition.SrgsGrammar.SrgsItem(searchRef) ' <--- '

    Dim opts As New Recognition.SrgsGrammar.SrgsOneOf(colorItem, searchItem) ' <--- '

    rootRule.Elements.Add(opts) ' <--- '

    gram.Rules.Add(rootRule)
    gram.Rules.Add(colorRule)
    gram.Rules.Add(searchRule)

    gram.Root = rootRule

    ...
```

Hope this helps someone in the future.